# How to see all the current enable properties in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

I intend to check out all current properties(like `fs.default.name`, etc.) set for my hadoop.

I've already googled on it, but with no luck. Is there any command that I can use?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any specific command to get this information all at once. I know that Hive has a nifty little command (set -v) that lists out Hive related properties.

But for Hadoop in general, you will have to go to HADOOP_HOME/conf directory to check the configuration files (XML), like hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml etc. to see the properties.

Comment: But the union of properties from hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml is not **ALL** the properties hadoop has, Is there some decent ways to list all the properties so that I can check it out conviniently.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a job's setup information in the jobtracker web UI. It contains a list of all the variables set for the cluster and the job. You'll have to be careful about which properties are set for your cluster and which are set by the job configuration. It's more a workaround but you can see the properties in one place.